# How to set volume of a SourceDataLine in Java

Tags: java, audio, controls

I'm trying to make an mp3 player in java and I can`t figure out how to control the volume in it.

I've tried something like this:

```
         // Adjust the volume on the output line.
         if (dataLine.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
             FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) dataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            volume.setValue(100.0F);
         }
```

Everything I have written until this code worked fine but apparently the dataLine is NOT control Supported because it jumps over this IF statement.

My question is this : Do you have any idea why this is happening and how could I work this issue around so that I could control the volume of my application?

Answer (score 4):

OK GUYS,

I found my mess-up. I actually forgot to call the dataLine.open(audioFormat) function which acquires the system resources.

So the code workes just fine, in case anyone has this kind of problems too

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to see what `dataLine.getControls()` will return ?

> Obtains the set of controls associated
>   with this line. Some controls may only
>   be available when the line is open. If
>   there are no controls, this method
>   returns an array of length 0.

If you want volume wouldn't you want to test for the `FloatControl.Type.VOLUME` control ?

Comment: dataLine.getControls() returns this

Master Gain with current value: 0.0 dB (range: -80.0 - 6.0206)
Mute Control with current value: False
Balance with current value: 0.0  (range: -1.0 - 1.0)
Pan with current value: 0.0  (range: -1.0 - 1.0)

I`ve been messing with my code in the meantime and realized that the Master Gain`s values IS actually changed but I can`t hear any cahnges in the song

Answer (score 1):

```
 float vol=50;
final FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) auline.getControl( FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN );
volumeControl.setValue( 20.0f * (float) Math.log10( vol / 100.0 ) );
```

vol=0 means **mute.**