# How to play a binary stream in Java

Tags: java, audio-streaming

This question is probably not even going to be asked correctly, but I promise you I'm doing my best. Here's the scenario: I wrote a little Java app that receives an audio stream from a server. Now, when I redirect the binary stream to a file, and pipe that file to mplayer, the audio is played correctly. What I want now though is to play the audio from my own app. Here's what I got so far:

The codec mplayer uses to play the stream:
AUDIO: 22050 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 0.0 kbit/0.00% (ratio: 0->88200)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))

What I coded so far:

```
public class StreamPlayer {
    public final AudioFormat audioFormat;
    public final DataLine.Info info;
    public final SourceDataLine soundLine;

    public StreamPlayer() throws LineUnavailableException {
        audioFormat = new AudioFormat(22050, 16, 2, true, true);
        info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat, 1500);
        soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    }

    public void startSoundLine() throws LineUnavailableException {
        soundLine.open(audioFormat);
        soundLine.start();
    }

    public void playStream(byte[] buffer) {
        soundLine.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }
}
```

and I call the playStream function for every received packet. No errors are reported, and no sound is heard. Am I even close to doing this, or off by a long shot?

P.S. I found some third party libraries on google, but I'd really like to keep them as a last resort.

Thank you!

Comment: does this `soundLine` play anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Get your Bytes into a ByteArrayInputStream and feed this into the streamplayer instead...
ByteArrayInputStream audioStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

Comment: Well thanks, but what do you mean by feed the ByteArrayInputStream to the StreamPlayer? The SourceDataLine.write() function only has a version that accepts a byte[] array. Do you have another function in mind?

Comment: your right... only read half way through your question when i thought of a problem i had with the javastreamingaudio class. Only figured out now that you're using a completely different thing. sorry

Comment: did you set the volume of the mixer?

Comment: here somebody seams to set the volume to play back sound http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668863/how-to-set-volume-of-a-sourcedataline-in-java

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't considered that. After a bit of research though, it seems this volume control is pretty buggy on my non-Sun version of Java, and I won't be able to get it to run on it. Now I don't know if I should hope that's where the problem lies or not. Thank you for your time and help though!